# Closed form solution of a definite integral?

Tags: calculus

I've never heard of a closed form solution, and I had this assigned to me and it is supposed to be 'review'. Could somebody at least get me pointed in the right direction here?

'Provide a closed form solution for the following definite integrals'

$$\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2}\ dx$$

$$\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x}\ dx$$

Comment: Post a link to the pictures in the comments. We'll be able to edit it into your post.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RZeQY.png

Comment: Why my edit is not accepted?

Comment: Sorry, just accepted it.

Comment: My guess is the professor asked for a "closed form" to prevent students from turning in the first step of integration by parts ($uv - \int v du$) and proclaiming the problem to be solved. Such a solution is still "open" in the sense that there is yet another integral to evaluate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** It is a fancy way of asking you to compute the two integrals.

For the first question, make the substitution $u=x^2$.  After a while you should get $1/2$.

For the second, integrate by parts twice.  For the first integration by parts, let $u=x^2$ and $dv=e^{-x}\,dx$.

Comment: So are you saying I should be using integration by parts for both, or just the second? I'm not really sure what a closed form solution is aside from what I've been able to read up on it by searching online.

Comment: Nevermind, I see where you said it is a 'fancy way of asking to compute the integrals'. Thank you! This was very helpful.

Comment: It's been a while since doing IBP, for the second one I ended up getting $-e^{-x}\(x^2 - 2x) - 2$, does that seem correct?

Comment: There is a little sign error, it should be $-e^{-x}(x^2+2x+2)$. Minus signs are a pain: if one does a couple of integrations by parts, probability of a sign error is high. Note that you can always check an integral by differentiating.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Disregard what I had typed here before, I had gotten confused.

Comment: If you keep having trouble, I can type out the stuff as part of the answer.

Comment: No more help needed, I got it. Thank you!